# Can Shopify-App Admin URLs be used as endpoints for Ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing an app for shopify.  The app will provide pages and functionality for the Shopify Admin area, specifically using App Bridge.

The app bridge URLs look like this:

```
https://[shop].myshopify.com/admin/apps/[my-app]/[my-path]
```

When you visit this page it loads shopify header/footer/menu, also an IFrame pointing to `[my-path]` on my site, for example:

```
https://example.com/[my-path]
```

I would like to setup Ajax requests using the same system of URLs.  for example I would use the endpoint as follows (I know this one doesn't exist, just an example):

```
https://[shop].myshopify.com/admin/apps/proxy/[my-app]/[my-path]
```

Then instead of rendering the IFrame with my URL, Shopify admin would proxy the request, forwarding it to:

```
https://example.com/[my-path]
```

Is this possible, or do I have to send the Ajax request directly to my own server? If the later, how is it recommended I do authorisation?  Can the HMAC that came in the original request be forwarded to the AJAX request (seems that would be bad, but not sure exactly why), or use a session that I establish on the original request?

Answer (score 0):

You setup an App Proxy in your App. You provide an endpoint in your App for the Proxy. Once this App is installed in a store, you can now call your App from the store itself, to the Proxy. Securely. That is the whole point of the App Proxy.

Comment: I believe you are talking about the Front End app proxy.  I am wanting admin pages to have a similar functionality.

Comment: You don't get to do that. You can do some Admin Extensions, like links, but you cannot alter Shopify Admin willy nilly like that.